# Alternative way of applying authentication in network security

Tags: encryption, authentication, network, cryptography, certificates

I have been reading and thinking lately about authentication and how this is achieved in cyber security. I notice that the only way of applying authentication is through the use of cryptographic keys ( e.g. digital signature). My question is: Beside cryptographic keys, is there another mechanism that helps to distinguish the legitimate and malicious entities ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To confirm the identity of the participants, there need to exist a unique ID which distinguish them. To attain authentication, we should be able to validate the unique ID.

Digital Signatures are one way of achieving the same. In signatures a trusted authority certifies that the entity communicating to you is infact the one it is supposed to be. You also have the option to verify it computationally.

HMAC is another way of doing it. HMAC also uses a key derived from a previously shared key between the entities and hashing.

To securely authenticate between two entities, an asymmetric signature, or a shared key based message authentication is required.

Answer (score 0):

It varies by protocol.

**PAP (Password Authentication Protocol)**

This is only for reference and should not be used. This is just sending a username and password in the header.

**CHAP (Challenge Handshake Authentication Protocol)**

Uses a challenge response method by generating a string and the client needs match it. This is more for reference as well.

**Kerberos**

To your point, uses secret-key cryptography to establish identity. Common, in most systems. It also provides a ticket to the user which can be used in Authorization.

**NTLM**

A Microsoft suite of security protocls for authentication, authorization, and integrity that uses the same concepts of challenge-response like CHAP.

**Open ID**

An open standard that uses the concept of decentralized authentication protocol and URLs to exchange identity information.

**Explanation**

Authentication is the act of proving that a user is who they say they are. Each example I provided are diffident protocols to achieve this. What I think you are miss-understanding is that Authentication as a whole is not subject to protecting prying eyes from eavesdroppers.

That is the role of other protocols such as HTTPS, which is most common and uses public key cryptography to establish a secure connection to another service.

*Example*

When connecting to Facebook, you uses a HTTPS connection (public keys) to establish a secure connection. You than provided your username/password, with authenticates you using if I remember correctly, their implementation of OAUTH 2.0.

The security of the connection, and the integrity of the users identity are exclusive. We tend to talk about them nominally, but they typically uses separate protocols.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the purpose of the encryption: it is there to stop third parties copying, forging or interfering with access credentials. Encryption supplies a secure point to point channel for exchanging information. It is possible to do this with the physical network - sniffing passwords was not considered a problem with serial terminals connected to a mainframe computer - but it is difficult to ensure the physical integrity of such a network nowadays. Also such an architecture is expensive, unreliable and inflexible compared with a shared medium network such as ethernet or wifi.

When the US still had silly rules about encryption export, a team in Sweden created a kerberos implementation which did not use encryption (eBones). I suspect it was probably reliant on seperating the physical medium of the network between the parties - though I'm guessing here.

It is possible to implement secure authentication without keys, but it does require secure hashing (and mutual authentication) but does carry a lot of complexity. This may have been the method used in eBones. Note that this still depends on a shared secret - which is a key, albeit not a cryptographic one.

But why bother now when key based encryption solves the authentication problem and also secures other data exchanges?